# Image resolution on Android getting extremely muddied

Tags: android, image

I am extremely new to Android development as a heads up. I have read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html) with no luck.

Right now the background of my application along with my ImageView are looking incredibly low res. The dimensions of my background image is 720px by 1280px with an image resolution of 72 and the ImageView is 538px by 113 px with a resolution of 72. When I make the resolution higher, my application crashes when uploading it to my Samsung S5.

My images:
[Offender 1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64950003/background_xhdpi.jpg)
[Offender 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0b2bb1t0960jr7z/logo.gif?dl=0)

What it looks like on my Samsung S5. It is very pixelated and muddied.
[image: View on Android Device]

My activity_main.xml looks like the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:background="@drawable/background_xhdpi">




    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="302dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: :O `my application crashes` is not a valid question here on SO. Android produces a very handy StackTrace in LogCat when an application crashes. You can [edit] your question to add specifics.

Comment: @MattClark the question was not, "my program crashes". the question was what was the suggested resolution that android supports and how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I have received was the following:

> Due to the responsive nature of Android design you will not find a
>   single dimension that works for all devices. You need to support
>   resolutions ranging from 240x320 up to 2560x1600. So what you want to
>   do is either design for the largest resolution, and make sure it
>   scales down well. Or target specific dimensions and save multiple
>   versions of your graphics. Another thing to remember is pixel density.
>   A lot of devices now use twice the amount of pixels to achieve these
>   resolutions. Some even use 640dpi instead of the standard desktop
>   "72dpi" Its a bit confusing, but it boils down to you needing to make
>   your images at least 100% bigger than the dimensions you want them to
>   appear on the device. If you logo is 538x113, make it 1076x226 and
>   then embed it at the normal 538x113 size, this will help with the
>   crispness of the lines.

- OP: [kvachon](http://www.reddit.com/user/kvachon)